# Facebook Scores API (iOS) returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/scores"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if(result && !error) {
                              id x = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

                              if(x) {
                                  id y = [x objectForKey:@"score"];
                              }
                          }
                    }];
```

Whenever it hits the "id y = [...]" line, the app just skips it and pretends like it never executed the line. When I go to the graph explorer tool I can see my scores.

I have requested the following permissions:

```
permissions:(
installed,
"user_games_activity",
"basic_info",
email,
"public_profile",
"user_friends"
)
```

Am I missing a permission?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its throwing a exception as you've missed a bit.  As its in a block the exception is easy to miss unless you step through it with a debugger:

```
id x = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
id y = [x objectAtIndex:0]; // This bit!
int score = [[y objectForKey:@"score"] intValue];
```